# Show all warnings and errors in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'am using Visual Studio Code Version 1.6.0.
Is there any possibility to show errors and warnings of all files in the current root folder?

At the moment it shows only errors and warnings for open files.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019**

ES-Lint has introduced a new task in VS Code. You have to enable it in the workspace setings.

```js
"eslint.lintTask.enable": true
```

Just go to terminal menu and select run task, then choose

```
eslint: lint whole folder
```

You can also auto-fix most problems by running the following command in the terminal:

```sh
.\node_modules\.bin\eslint.cmd --fix .
```

Reference: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

While we still await the problem scanner in VS Code, this is a good enough alternative if you use eslint.

<sub>**OLD ANSWER**</sub>

> Here is how you can see all problems in less than 10 seconds.
>
> You use a little trick.
>
> Open replace all in files `Ctrl + Shift + H`.
>
> Replace `;` with `;`
>
> Hit replace all. That's it. Now, check Problems.
>
> The assumption here is that all files have at least one semicolon. For
>   bigger projects, if you get a warning  asking you to refine your
>   search, just enter something that is common in all files but is not
>   present a lot.

Comment: Nice tip. I think parenthesis is the perfect candidate for this.

Comment: I need to make this everytime I open vscode, is there a way to make this all the time?

Comment: That, my friend, is gangsta!

Comment: By the way, that exact string is now deprecated, it should instead be `"eslint.lintTask.enable": true,`

Comment: Actually in a very large repo the replacement can take more than 10 seconds...

Comment: well this didn't end well. Apparently eslint can also include all js files somehow. 36k errors later... Jane how do you stop this crazy thing?

Comment: With the eslint package installed globally (`npm install -g eslint`) you can also just run the command `eslint .`, or if you have it installed locally (`npm install eslint`) the command is `.\node_modules\.bin\eslint .`

Comment: When running the task, I am getting this message: `Executing task: node_modules/.bin/eslint .  *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. ` and then nothing happens.

Answer (score 21):

**Very important:** Make sure to check the **Super cool! But i don't use the eslint** section. What I provide is a global solution! By setting up **tasks** and is explained in detail.

**Note:** If you feel the document is bloated make sure to skim and get to the titles that catch you! Even though every section may matter.  (TLDS (TOO LONG DO SKIM)).

## Javascript and Eslint

To add upon @Ajay Raghav answer!

This section show how to run the task on question! And the output of the execution!

For javascript, Vscode **Eslint** extension provide such a feature! Which if you are using Eslint (and not jshint) then you are having it already installed!

Usage as described on @Ajay Raghav answer! Are explained on the **Eslint** extension page!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

> `eslint.lintTask.enable`: whether the extension contributes a lint task to lint a whole workspace folder.

> `eslint.lintTask.options`: Command line options applied when running the task for linting the whole workspace (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface). An example to point to a custom .eslintrc.json file and a custom .eslintignore is:

```
{
  "eslint.lintTask.options": "-c C:/mydirectory/.eslintrc.json --ignore-path C:/mydirectory/.eslintignore ."
}
```

### Using the extension with VS Code's task running

From the doc:

> The extension is linting an individual file only on typing. If you want to **lint the whole workspace** set `eslint.lintTask.enable` to `true` and the extension will also contribute the `eslint: lint whole folder` task. There is no need anymore to define a custom task in `tasks.json`.

If you are not familiar with task! Here how you use the above!

- Go to Command pallet (CTRL + P + SHIFT)
- `> tasks run`
- Hit `Tasks: run Task`
- You'll find `eslint: lint whole folder`
- Hit and that's it

[image]

[image]

If eslint have no configuration setup! You'll get the following error!

[image]

If as such, Run `eslint --init`

And follow the interactive terminal!

Note if you don't have `eslint` command avaialble globally!

Intall it globally by running  `npm i -g eslint`!

### Result of the run

First the task run on the terminal!

[image]

[image]

You can see a detailed report! You can use the `click link` on terminal feature (`CTRL + CLICK`)! To directly open the file in question!

[image]

You can see too that the problems will automatically be listed in the **problems tab**! Which is cool!

## Super cool! But i don't use eslint

### Typescript and TSLINT

If you are a typescript user and you use TSLINT!
Then we need to go to the global way! And that's by creating a **task**!
Just like `eslint` did! (problemMatcher: `$tsc`) [you'll get to know what that is just a bit bellow].

(Make sure to check `TSLINT is deprecated` title)!

### I use a complete other language (c#, java, c++, php, python ...)

Yup yup! We need a global way! And the global way is through creating a **task**!

## Creating a task (The global way)

**(Support all languages (to be configured for each))**

We need to create a task!

The vscode documentation explains it pretty awesomely and in details!

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Check the documentation!

Now in short! I would resume **what a task is** in:

A vscode tool and feature! That allow us to setup tasks based on tools and scripts and run them within vscode! Analyse there output within vscode! And activating and profiting from other vscode features! That includes Click link navigation on terminal! And problems listing on problem tab! Auto fixing and suggestions! Integration with the debugging tool! ...etc! It depends on the task type!

[image]

A task get set through a setting file (task.json)! For a workspace or the whole user! (Some tasks types need to be set for only a workspace! They depends on the variables of a workspace)!

Also the task feature contains a lot of options and features! And is a big piece! For more just check the documentation!

**Back to our problem!**

We want **linting** of a **whole project**! And **errors detection**!

We need to have the **errors** **listed** on the **problems tab**! And preferably too with **fixes suggestions**!

All this gonna be done through a **task**.

#### Setting up the task! And core elements

Through vscode task features and integration! We need to configure it to allow good output! And integration with the problems tab!

The config will go as such:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "lint",
      "problemMatcher": ["$eslint-stylish"]
    }
  ]
}
```

(Here eslint through npm run lint)

The most important thing here to see! Is the type which determine the category and the task handling and launch setup! The script which define what get executed! And lastly and importantly **problemMatcher**!

For the whole tasks setting up! And options you can check the doc!

Here another example for **typescript**:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### TSLINT is deprecated

Yo ! You just shown how, a line above! Yea there is something important!
We can see **typescript** problems through **tsc compile process**! **Or** Through **TSLINT**! TSLINT will **support code style rules** and so on! **BUT** mmmm **TSLINT is deprecated**! And **ESLINT** is taking on! And in simple words **use** **Eslint**! And so **we can use Eslint for Typescript**! And that can be more rich!

Check the link bellow from the official link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

And humor face: Don't be affraid to do this

[image]

Already did!

[Should i migrate Tslint to eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/blob/main/docs/FAQs.md#should-i-migrate-from-tslint-to-eslint)

Another reason would be: TSLint is a linter that can only be used for TypeScript, while ESLint supports both JavaScript and TypeScript.

Reason for the choice and deprecation is:

> In the TypeScript 2019 Roadmap, the TypeScript core team explains that ESLint has a more performant architecture than TSLint and that they will only be focusing on ESLint when providing editor linting integration for TypeScript.

Check it [here](https://robertcooper.me/post/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project) and **how to setup .eslintrc.js without the migration tool**!

or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Which in short would be like:

```js
module.exports = {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", // set eslint parser
   "parserOptions": {
       "ecmaVersion": 12, // latest ecma script features
       "sourceType": "module" // Allows for the use of imports
   },
   "plugins": [
       "@typescript-eslint"
   ],
  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended" // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
  ],
  rules: {
    // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
    // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
  }
};
```

And sure : `npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`

> Make sure to use `eslint --ext .js,.ts` when executing eslint! Since by default eslint will only search for .js files.

Make sure to use the code styles versions that support typescript like this one for airbnb:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript

(The next section is the most important)!

#### Processing task output with problem matchers

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers

> VS Code can process the output from a task with a problem matcher. Problem matchers scan the task output text for known warning or error strings, and report these inline in the editor and in the Problems panel. VS Code ships with several problem matchers 'in-the-box':

- **TypeScript**: `$tsc` assumes that file names in the output are relative to the opened folder.
- **TypeScript Watch**: `$tsc-watch` matches problems reported from the tsc compiler when executed in watch mode.
- **JSHint**: `$jshint` assumes that file names are reported as an absolute path.
- **JSHint Stylish**: `$jshint-stylish` assumes that file names are reported as an absolute path.
- **ESLint Compact**: `$eslint-compact` assumes that file names in the output are relative to the opened folder.
- **ESLint Stylish**: `$eslint-stylish` assumes that file names in the output are relative to the opened folder.
- **Go**: `$go` matches problems reported from the go compiler. Assumes that file names are relative to the opened folder.
- **CSharp and VB Compiler**: `$mscompile` assumes that file names are reported as an absolute path.
- **Lessc compiler**: `$lessc` assumes that file names are reported as absolute path.
- **Node Sass compiler**: `$node-sass` assumes that file names are reported as an absolute path.

OK but you said JAVA, C/C++, PHP, Python ...
=> **We need to write our own problemMatcher**

### C/C++ (GCC)

The c/c++ support in vscode is added through the official ms extension `ms-vscode.cpptools`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

The extension provide `$gcc` problemMatcher!

A task will go as:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++ build all",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp", "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/build"],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that i just made the compilation to go for files in src (one level)

One can use cmake to build!

May like to check :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_build-helloworldcpp

### Defining a problem matcher

You can check the doc section bellow:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher

An example for gcc was given for c/c++!
A compilation outcome will be like:

```
helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prinft’
```

We set a matcher by the following

```json
{
  // The problem is owned by the cpp language service.
  "owner": "cpp",
  // The file name for reported problems is relative to the opened folder.
  "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
  // The actual pattern to match problems in the output.
  "pattern": {
    // The regular expression. Example to match: helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
    // The first match group matches the file name which is relative.
    "file": 1,
    // The second match group matches the line on which the problem occurred.
    "line": 2,
    // The third match group matches the column at which the problem occurred.
    "column": 3,
    // The fourth match group matches the problem's severity. Can be ignored. Then all problems are captured as errors.
    "severity": 4,
    // The fifth match group matches the message.
    "message": 5
  }
}
```

Directly in the task config that can go as:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp", "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/build"],
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 4,
          "message": 5
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see how staight forward the setting is!
You can check the doc link above for more details!

#### Defining multiple line problem matcher

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-multiline-problem-matcher

> Some tools spread problems found in a source file over several lines, especially if stylish reporters are used. An example is ESLint; in stylish mode it produces output like this:

```
test.js
  1:0   error  Missing "use strict" statement                 strict
✖ 1 problems (1 errors, 0 warnings)
```

I'll not go about the details check the doc! it explains it well (check the `loop` property too!

```json
{
  "owner": "javascript",
  "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
  "pattern": [
    {
      "regexp": "^([^\\s].*)$",
      "file": 1
    },
    {
      "regexp": "^\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+)\\s+(error|warning|info)\\s+(.*)\\s\\s+(.*)$",
      "line": 1,
      "column": 2,
      "severity": 3,
      "message": 4,
      "code": 5,
      "loop": true
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Modifying an existing problem matcher

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_modifying-an-existing-problem-matcher

Simply check the doc!

#### JAVA

oK now we know, how to make problems matchers! We didn't do java yet! So let's do that for it! (Wait i just googled and [here](https://gist.github.com/felixfbecker/1b03770e83bf795ebde8) someone that did it)

```json
{
    // compiles all files in the folder of the currently opened file
    "taskName": "javac all",
    "args": ["$env:CLASSPATH += ';${fileDirname}'; javac ${fileDirname}\\*.java -Xlint"],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "java",
        "fileLocation": "absolute",
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):([0-9]+): (error|warning): (.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "severity": 3,
            "message": 4
        }
    }
}
```

#### PHP

Here a php task too that use code sniff!

src (googling again): https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1102

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "PHP: CodeSniff Workspace",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${config:phpcs.executablePath}",
      "args": [
        "--standard=${config:phpcs.standard}",
        "--extensions=module,inc,install,php,theme,test,js,css",
        "--report=csv",
        "--basepath=${workspaceFolder}",
        "web/modules/custom"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "php",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^\"(.*?)\",(\\d+),(\\d+),(error|warning),\"(.*)\",.*$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 4,
          "message": 5
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Problem matcher and auto fixing

Ok so how the problem matcher make the auto fixing suggestions? The answer is **it doesn't!** It can be clear! Or you may said at the first time you get to see the problem matcher, hey it may have a relation!

It isn't! The **languages support or linters extensions** are what **provide such a feature**! And that through using **vscode Action api**!

Check

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeAction

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeActionKind

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeActionProvider%3CT%3E

**So simply:** The problemMatcher set how the output of a task run is parsed and outputed on the problems tab!
And the languages support extension implement the auto fixes! Or linters! (Extensions) [I can make a play ground extension if i want]!

To note too that the **yellow bulbe in the problems tab**! Works and allow auto fixing! Because the **problem matcher provide the line for the problem**! That get **mapped with the output of the extension fixing suggestions range**! That get precised on the [CodeActionProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeActionProvider%3CT%3E)!

Comment: One of the most ~~long~~ thorough answers I've seen

Comment: How can I run the task whenever I open the workspace?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_run-behavior  see folderOpen for runOptions property

Comment: Using '!' everywhere makes it lose its significance.

Comment: I am/was an energetic person. And then I got the remark, and I stopped that bad (relatively) habit. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 11):

Is not possible right now, the VSCode team have a [request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) for that feature that they are working in, so we must wait.

An alternative is to use a task runner to lint all errors in the project like the one created in [this guide](http://shripalsoni.com/blog/configure-eslint-in-visual-studio-code/).

Comment: This is more than a year old!

Comment: Is this a limitation of C/C++? Its 2018 and this is not added.

Comment: It's 2019, the feature is still not there.

Comment: For eslint users, the solution has been added to VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

For any like me who have encountered this question dozens of times with variations on the google search "c# vs code show all errors in all files", my issue was that I had too many files associated with my project – the C# extension by default starts error checking **only open files** when you exceed 1000 files total.

Go to Settings => Workspace => Max Project File Count For Diagnostic Analysis, and increase the value to wherever you think is reasonable.

Equivalently, add the following line to your existing settings.json, which increases the file count cutoff to 10,000.

```json
{
    // Rest of settings.json file here
    "csharp.maxProjectFileCountForDiagnosticAnalysis": 10000,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual code has an Extention for ESLINT to integrate the lint errors into the IDE. Whenever you save file, it will show its lint errors. See it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Answer (score -1):

Just run:

```
npx eslint --init
```

And configure it as needed