# Vscode doesn't show typescript errors if file isn't opened

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using typescript on react native. When there is an error in one of my files, vscode doesn't show it in "Problems" tab unless I've that file opened.

Before Opening the file:
[image: File not opened]

After Opening the file:
[image: File is opened]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json"
}
```

@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "React Native",
  "_version": "2.0.3",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["react-native", "jest"],
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

What do I do such that all errors are shown in problem tab and the files in sidebar have red underlines?

Comment: show your tsconfig.json. It might be a problem with your file inclusion settings. Ex. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23245

Comment: I cannot close it because of active bounty, but essentially this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116499/11613622 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234950/11613622

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Search for "*open user settings (json)*" and open the `settings.json` file.
3. Add this line there:

   ```json
   "typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true,
   ```

This is still an experimental feature. You can track this [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) for updates.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for eslint as well?

Comment: @TayyabMazhar For eslint you can enable a task. But you'll need to manually trigger it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39997022/11613622 . This GH thread might also be helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/91